# Customize assetPrefix in `next/dynamic` import

Tags: next.js

I am using `next/dynamic` to dynamically import a component like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Foo = dynamic(() => 'src/components/Foo')
```

I want to set the path at which my JS assets should be found dynamcically on the fly, I can't use `next.config.js` (nextjs is a peer dep in my package, and other complications). Is there a way to do this. I saw `dynamic` has an option called `loader` and `loadableGenerated`. I can't find proper docs on these options. Can these be used to modify the asset path on the fly?

[image]

Comment: The path used in `next/dynamic`'s import must be explicitly written - it can't be a variable. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#example:~:text=Note%3A%20In%20import,React.lazy..

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves the problem I'm having is that the chunks are using the wrong path and getting 404's on scripts. Is it possible to fix this?